# hacer un json de dos directorios en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo dos directorios que quiero unir y hacer un json pero no me esta quedando. Pongo abajo lo que estoy usando.

```
import json

uno = {
    'NoSol': '1192017',
    'idDocumento': '4fd174c8-3439-4c80-9b1c-1c3e6721f827',
    'Status': 'ENVIANDO',
    'Documento': 'D',
    'Id': 'prueba 1',
    'Tipo': 'SOLICITUD ',
    'Grupo': 'S',
    'Doc': '',
    'AGT': '1',
    'Path': 'null',
    'STATUS': 1
}

dos = {
    "Res": {
        "usuario": "Jesus",
        "sistemaId": "Clave",
        "resultado": {
            "codigo": 0,
            "subcodigo": 0,
            "mensaje": "Success",
            "descripcion": "descripcion",
            "fechaHora": "2018-01-04T12:43"
        }
    }
}

union = uno.items() + dos.items
```

saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Existe la posibilidad de que tengan claves comunes? De ser así ¿Cómo se debe proceder?

Answer (score 1):

`dict.items` en Python 3 retorna una [vista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) del diccionario y no puedes concatenar dos vistas. Este método si sería posible en Python 2, donde `dict.items` retorna una lista con las parejas clave-valor en tuplas, por lo que podrías hacer `res = dict(uno.items() + dos.items())`. Esto en Python 3 como digo no funcionará.

Puedes usar `dict.update` como muestra @AR4Z en su respuesta, creando una copia del diccionario primero para evitar que se modifique el original si no deseas que lo haga:

```
import copy

res = copy.copy(uno)
res.update(dos)
```

En Python >= 3.5 puedes usar la siguiente sintaxis en su lugar:

```
res = {**uno, **dos}
```

Ten en cuenta que si hay claves comunes se sobrescribieran dependiendo del orden en el que aplique la unión. **Ambos métodos no actualizan diccionarios anidados:**

```
>>> uno = { "a": {"b": 8, "c": 5}}
>>> dos = {"a": {"b": 68}, "e": 8}
>>> {**uno, **dos}
{'a': {'b': 68}, 'e': 8}
```

Si tus diccionarios contienen claves comunes y quieres actualizar a todos los niveles puedes usar `dict.update` pero de forma iterativa:

```
import copy
import collections

def update(dict1, dict2):
    for key, value in dict2.items():
        if value and isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
            dict1[key] = update(dict1.get(key, {}), value)
        else:
            dict1[key] = dict2[key]
    return dict1
```

La función actualiza el diccionario pasado como primer argumento con el segundo de forma recursiva.

Un ejemplo:

```
>>> uno = { "a": {"b": 8, "c": 5}}
>>> dos = {"a": {"b": 68}, "e": 8}
>>> res = update(copy.deepcopy(uno), dos)
>>> {'a': {'b': 68, 'c': 5}, 'e': 8}
```

Creado el diccionario puedes crear el archivo json con `json.dump`, p.e:

```
json.dump(res, "/datos.json")
```

o una cadena con `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 0):

podrías intentar esto:

```
import copy
uno = {
    'NoSol': '1192017',
    'idDocumento': '4fd174c8-3439-4c80-9b1c-1c3e6721f827',
    'Status': 'ENVIANDO',
    'Documento': 'D',
    'Id': 'prueba 1',
    'Tipo': 'SOLICITUD ',
    'Grupo': 'S',
    'Doc': '',
    'AGT': '1',
    'Path': 'null',
    'STATUS': 1
}

dos = {
    "Res": {
        "usuario": "Jesus",
        "sistemaId": "Clave",
        "resultado": {
            "codigo": 0,
            "subcodigo": 0,
            "mensaje": "Success",
            "descripcion": "descripcion",
            "fechaHora": "2018-01-04T12:43"
        }
    }
}


result = copy.copy(uno)
result.update(dos)
print(result)
```

en `result` guardo el contenido de `uno`, para no perder lo que ya trae `uno` y luego actualizo a `result` agregandole lo que tiene `dos`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer el json de una vez,  solo haz el diccionario completo, es decir, `{"uno": {..}, "dos":{...}}` y listo :), ahí tienes un json, luego para convertirlo utiliza el .dumps o .dump.